# I’m stuck at Ubuntu 22.04.1 tty1

Tags: boot, gnome, kernel, snap

I’ve been having errors with Linux, ACPI things that can be permissible and other things.

Just now however when I went to update the snap store, I found it pretty difficult and looked it up, found you can just remove it and re-install it. Things didn’t go as planned and everything came back as empty logos and bordered boxes no matter what I did.

I purged gnome-software and brought it back as well. I eventually saw another software store and saw I had “OS updates” and went for it and now I’m at tty1 wondering if it’s even possible to boot load again fresh or if I’m only stuck with the possibility of re-compiling the kernel as a complete noob to Linux.

Edit: Sorry for no clarification, the question I had was what to do in this case, which I found to just get a fresh boot from a re-formatted USB, I was able to reformat from a separate computer. I have a way with breaking my computer.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to what you are asking.

Comment: Sounds like you have a broken install.  Consider reinstalling ubuntu using the defaults (including wiping the disk).